# interpretation of a two-stage regression model

Tags: residuals, log-linear

I am running a two-stage regression model, where the first model is a log-linear model he outcome is log(y) = Intercept + 1 * x + Error. I then calculate the residuals for each observation of x.

The second-stage regression model is each residual for the ith observation:
residual(yi) = Intercept + 1 * x + Error

For the first stage regression, the interpretation of a unit change is a unit increase in X is associated with a 100* 1%  change in Y.

For the second stage regression, since the outcome is the log of residuals for the ith observation, what is the correct interpretation of a unit change in X? Is it similar to log-linear as before?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is precisely the regressions you want to run? By the FWL theorem, the coefficients of your second regression will be always zero as the residuals of the first regression are uncorrelated with the regressors of your two regressions.

Hence, the second regression seems somewhat pointless. (In the last sentence, it seems you contemplate the log of the residuals. That, in turn, will not be possible as the residuals themselves by construction have mean zero since we include an intercept, hence also include negative values, hence we cannot take the log.)

Example:

```
n <- 100
y <- runif(n)
x <- rnorm(n)

reg1 <- lm(log(y)~x)
reg2 <- lm(resid(reg1)~x)
summary(reg2)

> summary(reg2)

Call:
lm(formula = resid(reg1) ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6813 -0.5597  0.3155  0.7214  0.8908 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  6.263e-17  8.572e-02       0        1
x           -6.217e-17  7.985e-02       0        1

Residual standard error: 0.8557 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  1.25e-32,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.0102 
F-statistic: 1.225e-30 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I take the absolute value of the residuals to obtain only positive values of residuals. Then the second stage regression is run on the absolute values of the residuals of the ith observation. The data set is panel data and the overall intent is to examine the variance of panel data and reduction in variance between years, after accounting for correlation between the repeated observations on measured entities.